# Finding the posterior under Jeffreys prior

Tags: bayesian, posterior, jeffreys-prior

> Let $U \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$, $\alpha$ the rate parameter of interest and $a>0$ a fixed known constant, define
>
> $$ X = a U^{-1/\alpha}$$
> Find the Jeffreys prior, the posterior for $\alpha$ and determine the Bayesian estimator for $\alpha$ under quadratic loss.

First notice that
$U\in(0,1) \implies U^{-1/\alpha}\in(1,\infty) \implies X \in (a,\infty)$.

and $X$'s density is given by
$$\mathbb{P}(aU^{-1/\alpha}\leq x) = \mathbb{P}(U\geq (a/x)^{\alpha})=1-\mathbb{P}(U< (a/x)^{\alpha})=1-(a/x)^\alpha$$
thus differentiating with respect to $x$ we get
$$ f_X(x)=\alpha\frac{a^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}.$$
Taking the logarithm we obtain the following log-likelihood,
\begin{align}
\ln f_X(x) &= \ln\left(\alpha\frac{a^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}\right) =\ln(\alpha)+\alpha\ln(a)-(\alpha+1)\ln(x) \\
\ell'(\alpha;x) &= \frac{1}{\alpha}+\ln(a)-ln(x)\\
\ell''(\alpha;x) &= -\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\\
I(\alpha)&= -\mathbb{E}[\ell''(\alpha;x)]= \frac{1}{\alpha^2}
\end{align}
and the Jeffreys prior is given by $\pi(\alpha)=\sqrt{I(\alpha)}=\frac{1}{\alpha}$.

Proceeding to the posterior part, we have that

\begin{align}
\pi(\alpha)\mathcal{L}(\alpha;x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\alpha\frac{a^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}=\frac{a^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}
\end{align}
however, from this point on, I think I got something wrong,
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{a^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}d\alpha = \left.\frac{1}{x\ln(a/x)}\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^\alpha\right\rvert_0^\infty =0-\frac{1}{x\ln(a/x)} = \frac{1}{x\ln(x/a)} 
$$
such that $(a/x)^\alpha \overset{{\alpha\to \infty}}{\to} 0$ because $a/x<1$.

I would like to know if I'm on the right track, thanks in advance.

Comment: The distribution of $X$ is a Pareto distribution.

Comment: The posterior (and the integration) both need account for the constraint $x>a$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Those are great tips, I'll work around them and edit the post.